# Show that $d$ is direction of closed convex set.

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

This exercise is from Bazaraa Linear programming book.

And I don't see  the point of the exercise since the definition of direction is already given by hypothesis.

Am I missing something or the exercise it's not well stated?

> Let $S$ be a closed convex set in $\mathbb R^n$ and let   $x\in S$ . Suppose that $d$ is a nonzero
>   vector in $\mathbb R^n$ and that $x +\lambda d\in S$ for all $\lambda\ge 0$. Show that $d$ is a direction of $S.$

Comment: What is the definition of a vector being a "direction of a set" that is given to you?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг  $d\in\mathbb R^n$ nonzero is a direction of $S$ if for all $x\in S$, $x+ld\in S$ for all $l\ge 0$

Comment: In the question you have, $x$ is *one*  point of $S$. The definition demands that $x + \lambda d \in S$ *for all*  $x \in S$, so you have to use the fact that this holds true for one point, and that $S$ is closed convex, to show that it holds true for all $x \in S$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг oh

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I understand now. What can I do now? Do you think that by contradiction it's a good idea?

Comment: Let me see. If I get an idea I will post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that if $y \in S$ then $y+\lambda d \in S$ for all $\lambda >0$.

Note that for $t \in [0,1]$ we have $(1-t) y + t(x+\lambda d) \in S$.

Pick $\mu >0$, and let $t_n = {1 \over n} \mu$ and let $\lambda = n$ in the above equation (pick $n$ large enough so that $t_n \in (0,1]$).

This gives $(1-t_n) y + t_n x + \mu d \in S$ for all $n$.

Let $n \to \infty$ and use the fact that $S$ is closed to get the desired result.

Excuse the crude diagram:

[image]

To illustrate why closure is specified, consider the set $S=\mathbb{R} \times (0,\infty) \cup (0,0)$. Then with $d=(1,0)$ we see that if $x \in \mathbb{R} \times (0,\infty) $ then 
$x+ \lambda d \in S$ for all $\lambda$ but 
$(0,0)+ \lambda d \notin S$ for any $\lambda \neq 0$.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I need to prove, I wonder if a proof by contradiction is a good idea?

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: You changed a number between 0 and 1 by a sequence, Why? Is that permitted?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. As long as $u \in [0,1]$ and $x_1,x_2 \in S$ then $(1-u) x_1 + u x_2 \in S$. I can make $u$ be a sequence as long as it lies in $[0,1]$ and the resulting point will still be in $S$. The trick with the above proof is to pick the $\lambda$ and $t$ such that the product is $\mu$.

Comment: Okay:) . When $n\to\infty,t_n\to 0$ but also $\mu\to 0$. Thus $y+\mu d=y\in S$, but we wanted all $y+\mu d\in S$. Didn't we?

Comment: Read carefully, I let $\lambda = n$ above, that certainly does not converge to zero. It might help to draw a little picture, the geometry here is very straightforward and the proof immediate if you get the idea of the proof.

Comment: It's very confusing.. :) Do I also need to use this definition of closed set $S=\overline S$?

Comment: Convex analysis is very geometric and best understood with pictures. It really is a beautiful subject as our intuition serves us much better than with analysis in general.

Comment: Any of the usual definitions of closed set will work. The idea being that if $x_n \in S$ and $x_n \to x$ then $x \in S$. My little example at the end shows why you need closure.

Comment: You really should try to draw a picture to see where the point $(1-t_n) y + t_n x + \mu d \in S$ lies in the context of $y,x,d$. Think of a triangle formed by the points $y,x,x+\lambda d$ and let $\lambda$ get larger and larger. Then the triangle gets more and more like an infinite rectangle formed by the points $x,x+\lambda d, y, y+ \lambda d$. Then closure gives us the desired result.

Comment: I think I'm going to check the proof later, I need some sleep.

Comment: Good night! ${}{}$

Comment: Thanks for your help/time/... copper.hat :)

Comment: Hi:), I was checking the proof again and the comments and I don't connect both ideas, specially the one when you told me to draw a triangle, I did it and I think I could see the infinite rectangle, but how is that related to your proof?

Comment: @Anneliset.: I added a small diagram that might help.

Comment: Thanks, so when $n\to\infty$ this $(1-t_n) y + t_n x + \mu d \to y+\mu d$, therefore $y+\mu d\in S$  (due  $S$ is closed)?

Comment: @Anneliset.: Yes.

Comment: and therefore the proof is done since $\mu>0$ and is arbitrary, right?

Comment: @Anneliset.: Yes.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much 